# MySQL database query coding problem in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Hello I have this problem: I have MySQL Database with collation **latin1_bin**. In database I have table with collation **utf8_slovak_ci**. All collumns is **text**. In rows I have values with *ť í ž ľ š č(utf8)* chars, but PHP code returns values with utf8 chars replaced by *� , ?* and other not readable chars. In html head **I have set charset to utf-8**. Please help me. I have this code:

```
//From config file
define ("DATABASE_SERVER", "localhost");
define ("DATABASE_LOGIN", "root");
define ("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "root");
define ("DATABASE_DATABASE", "novymost");

mysql_connect(DATABASE_SERVER, DATABASE_LOGIN, DATABASE_PASSWORD)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("novymost")or die(mysql_error());
$results=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Downloads") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
// Print out the contents of the entry 

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
echo("<li>");
echo "<a href=\"".$rows["URL"];
echo("\">");
echo "".$rows["TITLE"];
echo(" - ".$rows["SIZE"]);
echo("</a>");
echo("<br/></li>");
}
```

Comment: What does your DOCTYPE look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run the query

```
mysql_query( "set names utf8" );
```

before runnign any other queries. This sets the connection charset

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Answer (score 2):

In php:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

In HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

In Database before queries:

```
mysql_query( "set names utf8" );
```

---

Or you can also convert you latin-table to a UTF8-table:

```
INSERT INTO utf8table (utf8column) 
SELECT CONVERT(latin1field USING utf8)
FROM latin1table;
```